# Comment an Activity in Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, workflow-activity, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio Workflow for SharePoint 2013, is it possible to comment an activity (not Annotation)? I have a Visual Studio Workflow, in which I want to temporarily exclude an activity. So, I want to comment it, instead of removing it completely. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I would suggest using "if" block with a false condition.